# Unable to deploy Windows VM: not to be sold in market: 'US'

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a Windows VM in Azure using Terraform. I am getting the error:

```
The Offer: 'WindowsServer' cannot be purchased by subscription: 'aaaaa-1111-2222-cccc-adf23ad' as it is not to be sold in market: 'US'. Please choose a subscription which is associated with a different market.
```

1. Terraform works with CIS L1 & L2 hardened image, so we know TF code is good.
2. Can successfully deploy `WindowsServer` to target sub using PowerShell and ARM.
3. Resource group is `uksouth`.
4. All resources are being deployed to `uksouth`.
5. Subscription is an Enterprise Agreement. As far as I know, there is no region directly associated with subscriptions.
6. Deployment uses an SPN.
7. Deployment is run from Azure DevOps via private agents on containers in `uksouth`.
8. `license_type` is set to `Windows_Server`. We have tried using retail.
9. SPN in target AAD was created with a guest account.
10. Guest account's home AAD is located in `United States datacenters`.
11. SPNs AAD is located in `EU Model Clause compliant datacenters`.

The only link to the US is with my AAD account (guest account) which is located in the US.

I think this is a red herring, but we've accepted the user license agreement using the SPN and a user. We've also deployed VMs using the UI which automagically accepted the agreement.

```
$Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
$Offer = "WindowsServer"
$Sku = "2019-datacenter-gensecond"

Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher $Publisher -Product $Offer -Name $Sku | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept
```

For bots, the full error is:

```
Error: creating Windows Virtual Machine: (Name "MYSERVER" / Resource Group "WindowsServers"):
compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed" 
Message="User failed validation to purchase resources. 
Error message: 'Offer with PublisherId: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer', OfferId: 'WindowsServer' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: 'a72b1a34-aa3a-6d32-3220-eaac50b32c35' 
The Offer: 'WindowsServer' cannot be purchased by subscription: 'aaaaa-1111-2222-cccc-adf23ad' as it is not to be sold in market: 'US'. Please choose a subscription which is associated with a different market. Correlation Id 'a72b1a34-aa3a-6d32-3220-eaac50b32c35'.'"
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful if you could share.

T. I. A.

Comment: you deployed with `powershell` & `arm` templates but `terraform` failing? If that's the case, I would check whether `plan` block is present in your tf code..

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the problem was caused by having a `plan` block.

**Solution**: Remove the `plan` block: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine

We had been using the Terraform code to deploy a non-Microsoft image (CIS) and that required the `plan` block, whereas `MicrosoftWindowsServer` Publisher does not require a plan block and the fact that we had it in the code caused this error.